# JavaScript adding minutes to date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to add 3 minutes to the time but instead of adding to the time, it instead acted like they're two strings and added them together like they're strings. What am I doing wrong?

```
var minutes = 3;
console.log(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
```

Comment: This is working for me (not behaving as strings), for example `new Date(new Date().getTime() + (3 * 60 * 1000))`. What are the types and values of `date` and `data.getTime()`?

Comment: When I run your code, I don't have the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```js
var minutes = 3;

let newDate = new Date().getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000);
console.log(new Date(newDate).toLocaleTimeString())
```

Comment: There is no need to create a new Date, nor to convert everything to milliseconds. You can add minutes using *setMinutes*.

Comment: Duly noted... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

To add minutes simply use the [`setMinutes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes) method:

```js
var date = new Date(/* whatever */);
var minutes = 3;
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + minutes);
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `new Date()`

```js
console.log(new Date().getTime() + 3*60*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const now = Date.now();
const threeMinutesFromNow = now + 3 * 60 * 1000;
console.log(`now: ${new Date(now).toLocaleTimeString()}`);
console.log(`3m from now: ${new Date(threeMinutesFromNow).toLocaleTimeString()}`);
```